# Access hard drive via hard drive label

Tags: windows, hard-drive, command-line, mount

In osx, it is possible to access a hard drive via its label: `cd /Volumes/SomeHarddriveLabel`

In unix, the same is possible via `cd /dev/disk/by-label/SomeHarddriveLabel`. This isn't strictly true, you would still need to parse the output like so:

```
cd $( df /dev/disk/by-label/SomeHarddriveLabel | sed -n 2p | cut -d' ' -f9- )
```

Is it possible to do this with windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this needs to be scripted:

```
:: cdrive.bat
@echo off
for /f "skip=1" %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk where VolumeName^="%1" get DeviceID') do (
    %%a 
)
```

Then:

```
cdrive label
```

will switch to the specified drive.